# get position from RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android

I have a recyclerview.Adapter class  this is my class :
when i'm pass int position in the MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder class parameters thats not works :(

```
public class Main_Recycle_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Main_Recycle_Adapter.MovieViewHolder> {
    List<Main> movies = Collections.emptyList();
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    Context context;

    public Main_Recycle_Adapter(Context context, List<Main> movies){
        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.movies = movies;


    }
//;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movies.size();
}


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;

    }
    //[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[


    @Override
    public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType ) {
            View row;
            if ((position % 2) == 0 ){
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_list3, parent, false);}
            else{row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_list3, null);}
        MovieViewHolder holder = new MovieViewHolder(row);

        return holder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Main thisMovie = movies.get(position);

        holder.tozih.setText(thisMovie.getName());
        holder.tablooo.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier(thisMovie.getLogo(), "mipmap", context.getPackageName()));
    }


    public class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tozih;

        private ImageView tablooo;

        public MovieViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tozih = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            tablooo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        }
    }
}
```

here i want position for even and odd rows :

```
 if ((position % 2) == 0 ){
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_list3, parent, false);}
                else{row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_list3, null);}
```

but position is still red with cannot resolve error
what can i do in this case?
thanks in advance

---

EDIT thanks to alex i've got this done :

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position )
{ int viewType ;
    if((position % 2) == 0 )
        viewType = 0;
    else
        viewType =1;
    return viewType; }
//[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[
@Override
public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType )
{
    View row;
    if (viewType == 0 ){
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_list2, parent, false);}
    else
    { row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_list3, parent, false);}
```

just needed that parent and false in the both of rows ....

Comment: You cannot access `position` directly. Use the `getItemId()` method instead. The `getItemId()` also need fix to get the position.

Comment: i've tested this but ... doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the `getItemViewType(int position)` method and put your condition there. (if (position % 2 ==0) and return view types based on that condition.) Of course you need to declare two view types and return the right one based on your criteria.

In your onCreateViewHolder you could check the viewType and inflate the right layout for that position.

Comment: i cant move the row and condition because of this :

Comment: MovieViewHolder holder = new MovieViewHolder(row);

Comment: No, you didn't get it. You don;t need to move that. You just need to move the if logic and return a view type. in your onCreateViewHolder you have a viewtype so you will use if (viewType == A) row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_list3, parent, false) etc. Btw you are inflating the same layout in both cases in your example

Comment: Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position ) {
        int viewType ;
        if((position % 2) == 0 )
            viewType = 0;
        else  viewType =1;
        return viewType;

    }

    //[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[



  Override
    public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType ) {

        View row;
        if (viewType == 0 ){
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_list3, null) ,,,,,
i've done this but not works

Comment: Are you sure you are not inflating the same layout in both cases? It should work. This code snippet actually inflating the same layout if ((position % 2) == 0 ){
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_list3, parent, false);}
                else{row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_list3, null);}  So if you want something different then you need a different layout on the else. Same as in the viewType case

Comment: this works but recycler items just loosing their marjin to the left and right . at all when i'm using the viewType  for if that's happen